# Is Google Sign-In a free or paid service?

Tags: google-signin

Is Google Sign-In a free or paid service? If it is a paid service, where is the price list published?

Comment: Even though this question is off-topic it's very useful and I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere else ;)

Comment: The more useful the question, the more likely it is to be closed.

Answer (score 21):

Google Sign-in is free. No pricing.

Comment: Everything on the firebase website seems to indicate otherwise. "Authentication" is billed, users are handled and stored. I don't see anything that indicates it is actually free to use Oauth through firebase, which makes sense since firebase manages your users for you.

Comment: Yes, Firebase has a free tier then it would cost money. You can achieve Google Sign in without Firebase directly through: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Depends on monthly user volume as mentioned from Janus Heide.

Answer (score 7):

The pricing is as far as I understand listed here (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing), but Google is throwing around a bunch of product names (https://developers.google.com/identity) so who knows?

Answer (score -9):

Google Sign-in is a free service. To use Google sign-in you have to use Google's Firebase authentication service. Pricing for Firebase has three tiers, you can see the pricing at this link https://firebase.google.com/pricing/.

Comment: You said Sign-in is free, but in order to use it I need to have Firebase, which is not.

Comment: You do not need to use Firebase to use Google OAuth sign in.

Comment: I am implementing Google sign-in in Flutter app(Firebase). It is not free.